# A number is defined 3Den if it is a multiple of 3 or has the digit 3 in it. Given a number num as input, count the number of 3Den between 1 and num

Tags: java

```
public int count(int num){
        //write your code here

        int i;
        int counter=0;
        for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
        if((i%3==0)||(i%10==3)||(i/10==3||(i/100==3)))
        counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Sample Input #1

```
count(15)
```

Sample Output #1

```
6 (3,6,9,12,13,15)
```

Sample Input #2

```
count(40)
```

Sample Output #2

```
21 (3,6,9,12,13,15,18,21,23,24,27,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39)
```

my code passes all test cases within 100 input but fails after 100.what to do?

Comment: add more explanation what do you mean by fails,  does it give a compile error or runtime error  etc?

Comment: like 300 is input in   which my code gives only 126 3den as output result is 138.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((i%3==0) || (i%10==3) || (i/10==3) || (i/100==3) ))
```

Bad if condition. For example number: 134 is number 3Den, but it will not return true in Your if statement

Hint: You need (for example) to create while loop and use exponent like: `((i / (10^a)) % 10)==3`

Approach 2: (less neat) would be changing `int i` to `String` and then using `String.contains()` or `String.indexOf()`

Comment: Yes, but by analogy You will get false for: 1300, 10300 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NextMultiple37 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NextMultiple37 obj = new NextMultiple37();
        int result = obj.findNextMultiple(1024);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public int findNextMultiple (int num) {
        //write your code here
        int i=0;
        for(i=num+1;i>=num;i++){
            if(i%3==0&&i%7==0){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }   
}
```